# How to close only the last opened Activity instead of all Activities?

Tags: android, kotlin

I build a radio-app in which the user can open a NowPlaying screen and from that screen two other screens. When I call finish from the last screen also the NowPlaying screen is closed. See this video: https://youtube.com/shorts/dsgxC9t0svQ

How can I only close one screen so that the user return to the NowPlaying screen?

To open the NowPlaying screen I use:

```
nowPlayingBtn.setOnClickListener {

    runOnUiThread {

        val intent = Intent(this@MainActivity, NowPlaying::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)

    }

}
```

To open the Just Played screen I use:

```
binding.justPlayedButton?.setOnClickListener {

    runOnUiThread {
  
        val intent = Intent(this@NowPlaying, JustPlayed::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)

    }

}
```

To close the screens I use:

```
binding.terugBtn.setOnClickListener {

     finish()

}
```

This code is added in both Activities: NowPlaying and JustPlayed.

I use this binding on both screens. When I press the "terug" (back) button on the JustPlayed screen only that one is called. It doesn't call both "terug" action. I tested that.

When I press the "terug" button on the NowPlaying screen only that one is called.

I use noHistory in the Start screen:

```
<activity
     android:name=".Start"
     android:exported="true"
     android:noHistory="true">
     <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER" />
     </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: Can you share the code that you use to navigate between activities?

Comment: There is still quite some information missing. Where is the code to finish called? Meaning, which activity? Also, do you have an attribute in your manifest file related to noHistory?

Comment: The code where finish is called in both the NowPlaying and JustPlayed screen. I do have a noHistory attribute in the manifest file. I'll add it in the question.

Comment: You probably have an extra call to finish somewhere. BTW, `runOnUiThread` inside a click listener is pointless - that callback will run on the UI thread already.

Comment: Could the first screen be destroyed when opening the second one?

Comment: Thx @dominicoder  I’ll remove the runOnUiThread :) didn’t know that.

Comment: I indeed had 2x finish. In the NowPlaying screen I had a onStop() with a finish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a finish() two times in my code: one on the "terug" button and one on the onStop() function.